# LDAP query to check attributes and group membership

Tags: ldap

I have written an LDAP query to check attributes and group membership for any user. But it is always giving a result

i.e.

```
(&(&(objectClass=person)(uid=myuserid)(c=US)(|(department=IT)(department=HR)))(!(|(memberof=cn=group1,ou=Groups,dn=pwcglobal,dn=com)(memberof=cn=group2,ou=Groups,dn=pwcglobal,dn=com))))
```

In this query, I need to check if this user is part of a country, belongs to any one of the departments and is NOT a member of any of the given groups.

But with this I am still getting a result even though user is part of group 2

Please help

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that 'myuserid' is a variable, then your problem is probably that the user is indirectly a member of group2.  In other words, myuserid is a member of group3, which is a member of group2.  The memberOf parameter does not search recursively.  Microsoft's Active Directory has the [`LDAP_MATCHING_RULE_IN_CHAIN`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa746475%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) filter to search recursively.  I am not aware of a filter that searches recursively that works with all LDAP servers.